# The meaning of conditional expectation: $\int Y(w)\mathbb{P}(dw|X(w)=x_k)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose our probability space is $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. In the lecture notes of my instructor, the following definition was given:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y(w)|X(w) = x_k] = \int Y(w)\mathbb{P}(dw|X(w)=x_k),
$$
where $X$ takes on distinct values $\{x_k\}$.

I don't quite understand how to interpret $\mathbb{P}(dw|X(w)=x_k)$.

My understanding is that $\mathbb{P}(dw)$ measures an infinitesimal set $dw$ which is presumably in $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$. When we are given $X(w)=x_k$, then our $\sigma$-algebra is reduced to events that could yield $X(w)=x_k$. So $\mathbb{P}(dw|X(w)=x_k)$ only measures sets $dw$ such that $w \in dw$ and $X(w)=x_k$? Does this make any sense?

Comment: there $\mathbb{P}(d\omega )$ just states the measure of integration, sometimes also written as $d\mathbb{P}$ or other similar notations. Its a notation, it doesn't mean that it measures infinitesimal things (as infinitesimals are undefined in standard analysis)

Comment: The point is the probability = 1 summing all events where $(X=x_k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object $Q(A,t):=\mathbb{P}(A|X=t)$, in the context of the question, its known as a probability (or stochastic) kernel, that is, a map $Q:\mathcal{F}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, for a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ the map $A\mapsto Q(A,t)$ is a probability measure, and for every $A\in \mathcal{F}$ the map $t\mapsto Q(A,t)$ is a measurable function.

Its an object that is part of one of the ways that we can disintegrate the measure $P(A,B):=\mathbb{P}(A\cap \{X\in B\})$ as the product $P(d\omega ,dt)=Q(d\omega ,t)P_X(dt)$, where $P_X:=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$.

If the event $\{X=t\}$ have positive measure, then $\mathbb{P}(d\omega |X=t)$ is the probability measure $\mu$ defined by

$$
\mu(A):=\mathbb{P}(A|X=t)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap \{X=t\})}{\mathbb{P}(X=t)}
$$

By example, using the above notations, we have that
$$
Q(A,t)=\int_{A}Q(d\omega,t )
$$
by definition of the Lebesgue integral (that is, by definition of what means the integration respect to a measure).
Hope you can see everything more clear now.

Answer (score -1):

That is the same as writing: $E[Y|X]=\int ydP_{Y/X}$
Or if you want: $E[Y|X=x]=\int ydP_{Y/X}(x)$
and is better understood.